# Pulling specific references in git repository

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

I'm working on a specific project inside of the Linux TV kernel project, and need to know how to pull the references for it.  They're stored in a branch on the repository called "experimental".  Basically, what I've done so far is this:

```
git clone git://github.com/torvalds/linux.git v4l-dvb 
cd v4l-dvb 
git remote add linuxtv git://linuxtv.org/media_tree.git 
git remote update 
git checkout -b media-master remotes/linuxtv/staging/for_v3.7
```

Ultimately, what I want to do is check out the commits from the staging/for_v3.7 branch (because that's the branch that's being actively developed on) and then merge the references from the experimental branch that apply to the drx-j drivers into it. The references are located at http://git.linuxtv.org/mchehab/experimental.git/shortlog/refs/heads/drx-j

So my question is, what is the command that I would use to pull all of the changes from that reference into my local repository?

Thanks, and have a great day:)
Patrick.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can add fetch to .git/config

```
[remote "linuxtv"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/staging/for_v3.7
```

you can check Pro Git section 9.5 The Refspec
https://github.com/progit/progit/

Comment: I'm thinking that I need to add (and clarify ) a bit more to this. I need to pull the changes from another repository (mchehab/experimental) and put them on top of the media_git repository that I cloned. Specifically the changes with the tag drx-j.  So, would I have to add another remote called experimental `git remote add experimental git://linuxtv.org/mchehab/experimental.git` then, `git remote update`, and finally something like `git checkout -b drx-j remotes/experimental/refs/heads/drx-j`?  The last command is what I'm not sure about.

Thanks, and have a great weekend.:)
Patrick.